# How to prove the equality of derivatives?

Tags: manifolds, riemannian-geometry

Suppose $M$ is a Riemannian manifold of dimension $m$, and $(U,x^i)_{1\leq i\leq m}$ is a local system of coordinates. Let the metric matrix on $U$ be $g=(g_{ij})$(with respect to $x^i$). Denote $G=\det g$ and let the inverse matrix of $g$ be $(g^{ij})$.

> Now I need to prove for any $k$, we have
>
> $$g^{ij}\frac{\partial g_{ij}}{\partial x^k}=\frac{1}{G}\frac{\partial G}{\partial x^k}$$

I think it should be easy but I just failed... Here is what I have tried.

Denote the companion matrix of $g$ by $(t^{ij})=G\cdot (g^{ij})$. Hence we have
$$G\cdot g^{ij}\frac{\partial g_{ij}}{\partial x^k}=t^{ij}\frac{\partial g_{ij}}{\partial x^k}$$
Now the question is: How to prove the R.H.S.=$\frac{\partial G}{\partial x^k}$?

$t^{ij}g_{ij}=m\cdot G $ right? Then if we consider the derivative w.r.t. $x^k$ then

$$\frac{\partial t^{ij}}{\partial x^k}\cdot g_{ij}+t^{ij}\frac{g_{ij}}{\partial x^k}=m\cdot \frac{\partial G}{\partial x^k}$$
But it's far from what I need..

Did I make something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your formula is a corollary of an identity called Jacobi's formula (you can see the proof in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula). If suffices to replace $t$ with $x^k$ to get the result.